# Insert to database from custom page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Now i'm using Wordpress and i have created a custom page into a existing theme.
I upload this page in to my webserver, I edited the .htaccess and isert the a code to access this custom file.

```
RewriteRule ^file$ file/ [L]
RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ file/$1 [L]
```

This works fine, now i want to go a step further.

I want to INSERT the value of `<input type="text" name="email" required="">` to the database.
So i need to know how to connect this stand alone index.php page with the existing WordPress database and insert `$_POST['email'])` to the table 'wp_newsletter'.

Comment: Rather than writing completely custom code, wouldn't it be better to do your script as a plugin, use custom post types, and that way you can get access to all the wordpress functions without the overhead of reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow @ScottMcGready's advice and put the functionality into a plugin and work within WP.  WP isn't efficient, but it is flexible.  If you want to continue down your current path you can simply load the WP core in your non-WP index.php file:

```
require_once('/path/to/your/wordpress/installation/wp-load.php');
```

Then use Wp_query as you normally would, e.g. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.

Comment: I second this but strongly advise against it, unless you really have/want to. Wordpress was built to be extensible through plugins. It's exceptionally good for this and the documentation is brilliant. Doing it this way ensures security and maintainability with your code. Think of the guy who's maintaining it after you!